# How to prevent page from making GET requests when url hash changes with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone application with a rails back end and am having some issues with the router.

I have a list of skateboard 'spots' with their respective id's in their href attribute. Whenever the spot is clicked I want to render the 'spot' view but I am having troubles because the browser is making GET requests to the href url to routes that do not exist in my backend. This is causing errors and prevents the router code from firing off which would send the correct request to the server. Is there any way to prevent the GET request from being made when an href element is clicked or am I misunderstanding something about how backbone router works?

What also confuses me is that I have an instagram-like footer that has href's for each of the different 'pages' of the app and when those get clicked it doesn't fire off a GET request, but whenever one of the 'spots' get clicked it fires one off.

I had the understanding that the backbone router intercepted all of the url hash changes and didn't make any requests with those urls.

**UPDATE:** adding delegate events and tweaking some other stuff and I got it to do the fetch correctly, however it is still making two requests, one to 'api/v1/spots/:id' which is correct, and one to 'spot/:id' which is causing it to put an error on the page. The view otherwise renders correctly though

Here is my router. The showSpot function is the one that would be making the correct request since it is fetching the model and the correct url's are defined in the model.

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'views/spots/spot_view',
'views/spots/spotlist_view',
'views/spots/upload_view',
'views/profile/profile_view',
'views/map_view',
'views/home/home_view',
'models/spot_model',
'views/profile/friends_view',
'collections/spot_collection',
], function($, _, Backbone, SpotView, SpotListView, UploadView, ProfileView, MapView, HomeView, Spot, FriendsView, SpotCollection){
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

initialize: function(){
},


routes: {

  ''          : 'home',
  'home'      : 'home',
  'spot/:id'  : 'showSpot',
  'spotlist'  : 'showSpotList',
  'upload'    : 'upload',
  'profile'   : 'profile',
  'map'       : 'map',

},

  home: function(){
    console.log('home view');
    var view = new HomeView;
    this.render(view);
  },

  showSpot: function(id){
    var self = this;
    var spot = new Spot({id: id});

    spot.fetch({
      success: function(spot){
        var view = new SpotView({model: spot});
        self.render(view);
        $('#back-button').show();
      },
      error: function(spot){
        console.log("Spot fetch was unsucessful in showSpot.");
      }
    });
    console.log('spot view spot id: ' + id);

  },

  showSpotList: function(){
    console.log('spot list view');
    var spots = new SpotCollection();
    var that = this;

    spots.fetch({
      success: function(spots) {
        console.log("Spot collection fetch was successful in showSpotList.");
        var view = new SpotListView({collection: spots}); //pass in collection
        that.render(view);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.lot("Spot collection fetch was unsucessful in showSpotList.");
      }
    });
  },

  upload: function(){
    console.log('upload view');
    var view = new UploadView;
    this.render(view);
  },

  profile: function(){
    console.log('profile view');
    var view = new ProfileView;
    this.render(view);
  },

  map: function(){
    console.log('map view');
    var view = new MapView;
    this.render(view);
  },


  render: function(view) {
    //close current view
    if(this.currentView) {
      this.currentView.undelegateEvents();
      this.currentView.$el.removeData().unbind();
    }

    view.render();

    this.currentView = view;
    return this;
  }


});


return Router;
});
```

Template in the spot collection view. Notice how the id is in the href.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme='b' data-filter-placeholder="Search Spots" data-inset="true">
    <% _.each(spots, function(spot) { %>
        <li class="spot"><a href="#spot/<%= spot.id %>"><%= spot.name %></a></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

SpotListView which contains the function "goToSpot()" that triggers the router.

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'collections/spot_collection',
'text!templates/spotlist_tpl.html',
'models/spot_model',
], function($, _, Backbone, SpotCollection, SpotListTpl, SpotModel){

'use strict';

var SpotListView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '#content',

template: _.template(SpotListTpl),

initialize: function(){

},

events: {
  'click .spot': 'goToSpot'
},

render: function() {
  console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
  this.$el.html(this.template({spots: this.collection.toJSON()}));
  this.$el.trigger("create");
},

goToSpot: function(source) {
    source.preventDefault();
    var hrefRslt = source.target.getAttribute('href');
    Backbone.history.navigate(hrefRslt, {trigger:true});
    return false;
}

});

return SpotListView;
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you call `Router.navigate` instead?

Comment: The problem is that the 'navigate' doesn't even get called (which I am assuming) because the page errors as a result of a 404 to '/spot/1' for example. I had a log statement inside of goToSpot() and it doesn't log anything.

Comment: Where exactly this `log` statement is placed?

Comment: Soooo I just realized that I hadn't run this.delegateEvents() for the spotList view. This caused the goToSPot() function to be called but now I am getting a weird underscore.js error saying 'title is not defined' hmm. And by the way the log statement was right above soruce.preventDefault()

Comment: Update: @raina77ow adding delegate events and tweaking some other stuff and I got it to do the fetch correctly, however it is still making two requests, one to 'api/v1/spots/:id' which is correct, and one to 'spot/:id' which is causing it to put an error on the page. The view otherwise renders correctly though.